# Failure "field should be initialised with an implementing instance of the interface"?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
    public class Player implements Comparable<Player> {

//Fields
private Name name;
private Rollable rollable;

//Constructors
public Player() {
    name = new Name();
    rollable = new Rollable();
}
public Player(Name name) {
    this.name = name;
    rollable = new Rollable();
}
public Player(Name name, Rollable rollable) {
    this.name = name;
    this.rollable = rollable;
}
```

Hello, for my constructors where i have put `rollable = new Rollable();` I am getting an error which states that it `Cannot instantiate the type rollable`.
Below i have added the JUnit test and i will also add the code for the Rollable class

```
        @Test
public void testDefaultConstructor() {
    Player p = new Player();

    assertEquals("Name field should be initialised with a default Name object ", new Name(), p.
```

getName()); 
        assertTrue("Player's rollable field should be initialised with an.       implementing instance of the Rollable interface", p.getRollable()         instanceof Rollable);
            }

```
@Test
public void testCustomConstructor1arg() {
    Name n = new Name("Joe", "Bloggs");
    Player p = new Player(n);

    assertSame("Player's name field should be initialised with and      return the same object received by the constructor", n, p.getName()); 
    assertTrue("Player's rollable field should be initialised with an implementing instance of the Rollable interface", p.getRollable() instanceof Rollable);
}
```

Now below is the JUnit test for the default constructor whcih is also giving me the failure of `Players rollable field should be initialised with an implementing instance of the Rollable interface`, however, all of my other JUnit tests are passing.

```
        @Test
public void testDefaultConstructor() {
    Player p = new Player();

    assertEquals("Name field should be initialised with a default Name object ", new Name(), p.getName());
    assertTrue("Player's rollable field should be initialised with an implementing instance of the Rollable interface", p.getRollable() instanceof Rollable);
}
```

The code for my Rollable class is as below;

```
    public interface Rollable {

public void roll();

public int getScore();
```

}

The methods for my rollable code are as below;

```
        //Methods
public Name getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(Name name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Rollable getRollable() {
    return rollable;
}
public void rollDice() {
    rollable.roll();
}
public int getDiceScore() {
    return rollable.getScore();
}
```

All help will be appreciated as i am struggling with the failures, thank you.

Comment: As a general strategy, only have **one** constructor which "does something". Make the other constructors - if you actually, really, need them at all - call another constructor. For instance: `public Player() { this(new Name()); }`. Then: `public Player(Name name) { this(name, getRollable()); }`. Now, only `public Player(Name name, Rollable rollable)` does any actual work: the other two overloads merely provide default values for the parameters.

Comment: But I'm going to guess that your `getRollable()` method is actually returning `null`. (Please edit the question to add the implementation of that method).

Answer (score 0):

Your `getRollable()` method is:

```
public Rollable getRollable() {
    return rollable;
}
```

So, if you call that from a constructor, for example:

```
public Player() {
    name = new Name();
    rollable = getRollable();
}
```

then `rollable` will be assigned the value of `rollable`, which is by default `null`.

As such, when you call `getRollable()` again in the test, you get back the value you assigned to the field - `null` - and by definition - `null instanceof Rollable` is false.

Instead, you need to create a new instance of `Rollable`, for example:

```
rollable = new Rollable();
```

(Don't know if it is directly instantiable. You've not provided the declaration of the `Rollable` class).

Comment: Thank you for the help, however, i am still getting an error when i tried to code `rollable = new Rollable();` I get the error that `Cannot instantiate the type Rollable`, i will also update my question and add the Rollable class code

Comment: @lukesmith `Rollable` is an interface. So you can't instantiate it (this is what I mean in the penultimate sentence). You either have to assign it a sensible default value. If there is no sensible default, this means that it doesn't make sense to provide a constructor which needs to provide that default: remove that overload, and thus require the caller to provide the value explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Rollable` is an interface, and in Java you can only create instances of non-abstract classes.

So you need to write at least one class that `implements Rollable`. Of this class, you can create instances.

Why is that so?

Have a look at e.g. the `Comparable` interface (serving me as an analogon to your `Rollable`). `Comparable` denotes classes that support some kind of greater / equal / less than comparison, by requiring the class to have a method named `compareTo()`. If you were to instantiate a `Comparable`, what would you expect to be the result? A `String`, a `Long`, a `Double` or what? And the same applies to your `Rollable`.

An interface defines some requirements that implementing classes must fulfill, but they don't denote classes themselves, so you can't create (direct) instances of interfaces.